# Flexslider not syncing with dynamic items

Tags: foreach, flexslider, advanced-custom-fields

I have flexslider activated with a ACF for each loop using this code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // The slider being synced must be initialized first
    $('#gallerycarousel').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        directionNav: true,
        itemWidth: 300,
        itemMargin: 10,
        animationLoop: true,
        asNavFor: '#galleryslider'
    });

    $('#galleryslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        directionNav: true,
        sync: "#gallerycarousel"
    });

});


<div class="flexslider" id="galleryslider">
    <ul class="slides">

    <?php
    $gallery = get_field('fullgallery');

        foreach( $gallery as $galleryImage ): 
        $image = $galleryImage['url']; ?>

            <li style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image; ?>')"></li>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>
</div>

<div class="flexslider" id="gallerycarousel">
    <ul class="slides">

        <?php
        foreach( $gallery as $galleryImage ):
        $image = $galleryImage['url'];
        ?>

            <li style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image; ?>'); background-size: cover;">

                <div class="viewImg">
                    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="<?php echo $image; ?>" title="<?php echo $galleryImage['caption']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                </div>

            </li>

            <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $galleryImage['url']; ?>" />
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>
</div>
```

My issue is that on click of a thumbnail, it takes me to the wrong large image, I have tried re-downloading flexslider but no luck, I have also tried replacing the for each loop with just static items and, that seems to fix it.

I am unsure on how to get it to work with the foreach loop, does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems removing this: `<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $galleryImage['url']; ?>" />` fixed the issue.